# Sending message to specific person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to get the bot messaging me what the user reported by !report @user#1234 Reason

message.author.send(`${user} **Reported** ${userf} **for** ${reportReason}`)
                            ^

ReferenceError: user is not defined

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "report")){
    let author = message.member;
    let sentuser = author.user.tag;
    const userf = message.mentions.users.first(); 
    const reportReason = args.slice(1).join(' ');

    const userID = '123456789'; //My id

    async function declaredAsAsync() {
      const user = client.users.get(userID) || await client.fetchUser(userID);}



 message.author.send(`${user} **Reported** ${userf} **for** ${reportReason} `)
```

}

I want it to work the right way without errors :>`

Comment: where is error occur? this `author.user.tag;` or this ` message.author.send(`${user}` ?

Comment: Natsathorn At message.author.send(${user}

Comment: why did you have `client.users.get(userID) || await client.fetchUser(userID)` in the same line ?

Comment: `user` is declared in the scope of the `declaredAsAsync` function, but you're attempting to access it outside

Answer (score 2):

You're using `user` outside of the [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) that you defined it. In this case, you define it inside `declaredAsAsync()`, but you try to access it outside of that function.

To resolve the error, you can move this line to *inside* the function:

```js
message.author.send(`${user} **Reported** ${userf} **for** ${reportReason}`)
```

Comment: Oh okay thanks, that fixed it. But how do i make the bot text me about the report?

Comment: I have no idea how to use discord.js. I just saw you asked about user is not defined. Then I come to help. You better give it a try. It is not too hard. Once you got a problem comeback and search here. Still got no answer, feel free to ask. People here willing to help just give it a try and show us where did you stuck.

Comment: @mackex5x5 Change the line to `user.send(...)`.

Comment: @mackex5x5 that's because of you never used it. Just declare

Comment: @mackex5x5 I feel like the reason you're declaring a new async function is because you need to use `await`. What you're missing though is that the event callback is a function itself. So by declaring the callback as async, you don't need to write and call a new inner function just to use the async/`await` style. For future reference, in top level code, you can define a self-invoking async function (`(async (params) => {...})(params)`) which would call itself immediately after declaration.

Comment: Sorry, i did not totaly understand @slothiful